# Виртуализация включена, но WSL этого не видит

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, wsl

Пытаюсь установить Ubuntu через wsl, выдает ошибку: не включена виртуализация (на скриншоте видно), Платформа виртуальной машины и виртуализация точно включена. Пк перезагружал.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]